# Register the push enabled application for push service on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I installed SDK push notification (`server BPSS` and client enabled in `push SDK`).

But I got an **error** when I click register and enter login and password I obtain error *`"Request to register failed. Caused by java.io.IOException:Network Operation [Subscribe] Failed. Make sure the content provider url is accessible"`*.

What should I do to complete registration ?

Comment: Have you got the id and url to access from blackberry push team?

Comment: yes I got application id,PPG Base URL,Push Port,App ID......

Comment: if its live push use "http://pushapi.na.blackberry.com" , if its eval, use "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com"

Comment: it uses http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com

Comment: ok make sure you are using the eval app id rather than push api

Comment: didn't get you you mean in setting the App ID or where?

Comment: when you set the appid for push. make sure you are using the eval app id

Comment: BIS is active on your devise ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using BIS services(BlackBerry Internet Services).